# Netsuite with Mule ESB

Tags: mule, netsuite

How do I obtain the modified records of employees for a certain period of time?
How to get list of role?
how to delete record of role and department from employee?
I'm using the [Mule Cloud connector to NetSuite](https://github.com/mulesoft/netsuite-connector/tree/1.0).

Thx.